# How can I access variable outside function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, extjs, global-variables

I have this code

```
function(config) {
  items=[];
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'url',
    success : function(resp) {
      items = [a,b]
    }
  });
  console.log(items);
  return items;
},
```

I want the items array to be available in main function but its coming empty.

Comment: This has been answered many times. Search for something like "ajax data outside of success handler"

Comment: @palsingh that was just dummy item

Comment: It can't be available in the main function unless the AJAX request will be synchronous i.e. stop the script until it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this has been answered countless of times, I'll show you a quick example on what you need to do. In short, you can't access data recieved by an ajax call outside of the success handler. You'll need a callback:

```
function ajaxStuff(config, cb) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'url',
            success : cb
        });
}

var config = {};

ajaxStuff(config, function(resp){
   //handle the ajax response here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yrd7r/

Comment: Please add some explanation.  For someone who doesn't understand async, this doesn't explain why it needs to be done this way.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wasn't finished :) If he want's a more detailed explanation, there are hundreds of other SO threads answering this very question.

Comment: i cant understand ur example. can u just give example from my mycode. what is cb in ur code and what will be its content

Comment: @user26 If you want an example with your code you need to give me some more context. Show me more of your code.

Comment: This is my code  http://pastebin.com/VNV4Mk50

Comment: @user26 http://jsfiddle.net/Yrd7r/

Comment: Thanks for that but in which function do i need to put return in callback or main function get items . i want to return items when i call obj.getitems but how can callback pass items to get_items

Comment: @user26 You don't use a return statement, you use the callback like in the demo.

Comment: I need to get the items from that function and then pass somewhere else. is it possible

Comment: @user26 Sure. Again, handle it withing the callback.